# RequestScoped managedbean created every changes in the view?

Tags: jsf-2, managed-bean

I have a question about `RequestScoped` `ManagedBean` :

It seems like the `RequestScoped` `ManagedBean` is created every time we change something in the view, indeed, if we change value of `<p:selectOneMenu>`, for example, method declared as `@PostConstruct` is called.

I think this will slow the application.

Can some explain more this issue ?

Comment: Just put bean in view scope if you need it to live as long as the view? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031885/how-to-choose-the-right-bean-scope/

Answer (score 2):

> It seems like the RequestScoped ManagedBean is created every time we change something in the view

`RequestScoped` ManagedBean will be created for every request made. If changing something in the view is going to make a new request, e.g. ajax request, then the bean will be created and its method annotated with `@PostConstruct` will get every time bean is created

> I think this will slow the application

What kind of operation are you performing in that PostConstruct annotated method? What is it that you need everytime a request is created? If you could avoid that, then there is no need to write a `PostConstruct`